# elastic beanstalk 502 error - drupal container - connection refused upstream

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, drupal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

nginx access logs show 502 errors
nginx error logs show: failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /health HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.0.2:3000/health", host: "x.x.x.x"

the drupal site is running health module that uses path /health. this container runs fine in ECS. the docker-entrypoint.sh script just executes a few drush commands.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM drupal:9-php7.4-apache

# code that installs soap, drush, composer etc ...

# Assign the drupal web to apache web folder
RUN rm /var/www/html
RUN ln -s /opt/website/web /var/www/html

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

nginx.conf in .platform/nginx

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name localhost;

      ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;
      ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header  Connection "";
        proxy_set_header  Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
  }
}
```

I have a couple of .ebextension files but those are for env variables. The container will build, start, connect to the database but then fail health check and eventually get terminated. any help or pointers would be great.